# Qt FlowLayout example - how to get sizeHint to be called when layout changes?

Tags: python, pyside2, flowlayout, qlayout

I want to arrange a bunch of QPushButtons in a layout so they will wrap horizontally (like text). I'm trying to use the Qt example FlowLayout in PySide2.

I've posted a simple example [revision 2 here](https://gist.github.com/Boon-in-Oz/5134664a13cffb6f67075edfe2ff6f8a)

(This is based on the official example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html), which is why I'm so perturbed it doesn't work well.)

Specifically, it works well when the window is large enough:

[image: window works well when large wide] 
[image: window works well when large tall]

but doesn't prevent the window from being shrunk down small, whereas a VBoxLayout or GridLayout would:

[image: window can be resized too small]

I think the minimum size should depend on the current width. This should be a minimum size:

[image: wide minimum size]

and so should this:

[image: narrow minimum size is tall]

**How can I get the layout to prevent its parent from being shrunk so small that its contents aren't visible?**

sizeHint() and minimumSize() always return the size of a single item, which I thought was the problem. However if I rewrite them to take into account all items at the current layout width, it doesn't matter, because both are only called once, when I create and populate the layout.

My best idea so far is to call update() from heightForWidth(), roughly this:

```py
def heightForWidth(self, width):
    oldWidth = self.geometry().width() - 2 * self.contentsMargins().top()
    oldHeight = self.doLayout(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, oldWidth, 0), True)
    height = self.doLayout(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
    print 'heightForWidth', width, oldWidth, height, oldHeight
    if height != oldHeight:
        self.update()
    return height
```

full sample with changes to minimumSize and doLayout is [revision 3](https://gist.github.com/Boon-in-Oz/5134664a13cffb6f67075edfe2ff6f8a).
 It works sometimes, but has several problems:

1. When the layout is first created there are constant calls to update(). I think the call to update() triggers a call to heightForWidth() and for some reason the width passed in is not close to the "oldWidth" that I calculate until I resize the window, even by a single pixel.
2. As soon as I resize the window, calls to heightForWidth() stop completely, and minimumSize() stops being called, and I can no longer resize my window smaller than the last size calculated. I've no idea why.
3. (Much less important) `self.geometry().width() - 2 * self.contentsMargins().top()` does not return the width that was last passed to heightForWidth (even when top/bottom/left/right margins are identical), though I took it from other code in the example. This doesn't usually matter but at certain widths it causes a flurry of calls to update()

I suppose I'm doing it all wrong. Can it be done right?

Comment: Maybe an image of what you get now and what you want to get, clearly explain your question

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use explicitly `setMinimumSize` on the `QGroupBox`, so that when the user shrinks the main window it won't collapse to the size of a single item? Your question is a bit abstract, you may need to provide a simple example.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. I've updated my question with a modification of your test code.

Comment: @GreenCell I don't understand what you mean, though maybe that's because my original question wasn't clear. For a flow layout (I think) the minimum size should depend on the current width. It might be long and thin, or short and wide. I want to prevent it from short and thin simultaneously.

Comment: Ah thank you for editing the question it's much clearer now. I see, you want to dynamically get its minimumHeight depending on its width so the buttons are never cut off. I would imagine you have to calculate how many rows the items are creating and base it off that. It's a great question, I'll have a think about it. Maybe sir @eyllanesc has a trick up his sleeve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ported the original/official example to PySide2 now, and it works without changes. I'm not sure what was preventing it from working before.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify just the `setGeometry()` and `minimumSize()` functions. I worked in C++, but it is easily modified to Python.

First, I changed the QSize returned by `minimumSize()` to take into account the current size of the layout and subsequently set the height for the returned QSize. Then, I call `update()` in `setGeometry()` to force the layout to reexamine the `sizeHint()`. Below is an example of the code.

```
QSize FlowLayout::minimumSize() const
{
    QSize size;
    for (const QLayoutItem *item : qAsConst(itemList))
    {
        size = size.expandedTo(item->minimumSize());
    }
    const QMargins margins = contentsMargins();
    size += QSize(margins.left() + margins.right(), margins.top() + margins.bottom());

    // ADDED CODE **************************************
    auto layoutSize = this->contentsRect();
    size.setHeight(heightForWidth(layoutSize.width()));
    // *************************************************

    return size;
}

void FlowLayout::setGeometry(const QRect &rect)
{
    // ADDED CODE ************************************
    update();
    // ***********************************************
    QLayout::setGeometry(rect);
    doLayout(rect, false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.
In the meantime I've updated to PySide2, and the official example works correctly for me when ported.

Comment: Hi @wei-keat-tey, I was trying your solution, but contentsRect() seems to always be QRect(0, 0, 0, 0) when called from within minimumSize(). Any idea why it might be that way?